# how to make Tabs from notepad++ behave like in windows' 7 notepad

Tags: windows-7, notepad++

I'm using notepad++ on daily basis, but sometimes, just for fast notes, I use also the notepad provided in Windows 7. When I want to organize the data (making a sort of table) and I'm using Tabs (in notepad), if I reopen the file in notepad++, the data don't (vertically) align anymore (although I've set up the notepad++'s tabs size to 8)

My question is, how can I make the file look/behave the same both in notepad and in notepad++? Or more precisely, what settings do I have to do in notepad++ in order to have the same look in both programs.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Preferences -> Tab settings -> select 'Default' and change the size to eight

Windows notepad has tab = 8 spaces by default, Notepad++ has tab = 4 spaces.